# ArcMap Image Analysis Window - functionality is grayed out

Tags: arcmap, image, digital-image-processing

In ArcMap's Image Analysis Window, none of the tools are available even though I have a raster selected in the window.  I do not have Editor turned on.  I can't identify why the Processing tools are not available to me.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is this using QGIS or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image is **highlighted** in the list, not just checked.

Comment: Not for stats padding or anything, but the answer could be accepted, per https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Click on the raster which is selected in the window (in your example, click on the `dedem1m_Corrected2_m_Redefined` on the left window, then the Processing tools on the right are available.

Answer (score -3):

I literally just had this same issue. Highlight the image name, don't just check it.